# sending name instead email address usin mailto

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, outlook, mailto

I'm creating an in-office webpage that you can choose the people you want to sent your mail to with check boxes, and then press a button that will open outlook and send them an email.

I'm trying to send it with names, instead of email addresses.

Example:

Tomer Amir; John Do; ... etc.
And not:

tomer@office.com; john@office.com; ...

the problem is that outlook does not recognizes the names...

my code:

```
function getSelectedCheckbox(){
var names = "";
$('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').each(function() {
    names += $(this).val();
});
document.getElementById('selectedrows').value = names;

}

function sendMail(){
    getSelectedCheckbox();
    var mails = document.getElementById('selectedrows').value;
    window.open('mailto:'+mails+'?subject=subject&body=body');
}
```

it returns a string that looks like this:

Tomer Amir; John Do;

Thanks!

Comment: Why *should* it recognise the names? They *eventually* have to be email addresses (you can't send email to a simple name, even with Exchange). I think you've been confused by the auto-complete behaviour of the email address input field in Outlook (when used manually) - it replaces the (partial) name you give with an icon (of sorts) that represents a contact (which is treated internally as a real email address) in much the same way that the `tags` system works on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending both email and name in this format:

Tomer Amir (tomer@office.com); John Do (jhon@office.com);

and it worked.